# Usage of Update-Database in EF Migrations when deployed in Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

Context: I have my ASP.NET MVC4 solution deployed in Azure. 

My MSSQL Server Database is also there, in Azure.

I currently deploy this way:

1. In web.config I change the connection string from local database (sdf) to azure database (`connectionString="Server=tcp:.....database.windows.net, ..."`)
2. Right click on project name (visual studio), and then "Publish"

So, **my question is**:
How do I use the `Update-database` command in the Package Manager Console?

Is it this way?

1. Same step #1 from above
2. Run Update-Database

I want to be sure about this. Also, I guess I should add the firewall IP exception from Azure before running step #2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are right. At least that is how it worked for me:

- Enable a firewall rule for your current IP Address in Azure
- Update your web.config connection string according with your Azure Database conneciton string.
- Run Update-Database in your Package Manager Console

On the other hand, due to your situation ("I want to be sure about this") i recommend to duplicate the database in Azure and test this steps with this backup.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT** due to comment:

Check this out: [Triggering EF migration at application startup by code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508280/triggering-ef-migration-at-application-startup-by-code)

Comment: Is there a programmatic way of doing the update? Like in global.asax with Application_Start. So that I continue just deploying from VS (and nothing more from VS)

Comment: Check this out: [Triggering EF migration at application startup by code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508280/triggering-ef-migration-at-application-startup-by-code) - Comment [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2306264) by anonymous user

Comment: That was my comment but i forgot to log in to reply :S