# System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings retrieves old value at runtime

Tags: .net-core, app-config, xaf

In my dotnetcore winforms application I am able to get the connection string correctly from app.config when running in the IDE

```
  var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

For run time, I thought I would just replace the connection string in the MyApp.Win.config file. However the connection string is being pulled from MyApp.Win.dll.config

[The docs are here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files)

Comment: This may be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61786767/no-connection-string-named-connectionstring-could-be-found-in-the-application