# Code Based Code First Migration

Tags: entity-framework, migration, code-first

How to implement Code First Migrations without Package Manager Console commands. I want to implement Code First Migrations logic by using code.
I don't want to write Following commands

```
PM    >      Enable-Migrations
PM    >      Add-Migration
PM    >      Update-Database
```

Please tell me the best practice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using the migrate.exe tool that is supplied when you install EF package.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj618307.aspx

You could theoretically call this from your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would be adverse to the first two, but the last I totally understand. You are looking for the DBMigrator class. You can use this to check how many migrations need to be run, and do the migration to any version. If you can do it with Update-Database, you can do it in code. I've referenced a similar example below.

[Triggering EF migration at application startup by code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508280/triggering-ef-migration-at-application-startup-by-code)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, In fact I want to implement all the following three commands

    PM    >      Enable-Migrations
    PM    >      Add-Migration
    PM    >      Update-Database

in my code. If I change any thing (add  or delete a field ) in my model classes then it synchronize the code with database automatically using logic in the code (whether it is in Global.aspx or in DbContex class).

Thanks,